# How can I rewrite my root directory pages url to directory

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have below urls in my website
http://www.abcdef.com/about.php
http://www.abcdef.com/contact.php

I want to change the address URL look as below 
http://www.abcdef.com/about-us/
http://www.abcdef.com/contact-us/

How can n achieve this without making new directories? How can I rewrite the URL, what Rewrite rule should I write?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about/$ about.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\\ /about\\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^about.php$ /about-us/ [L,R=301]
```

this should work for the top level directory.